# HTML CSS Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

[image: Drop down menu before and after]

I have a React website that has a custom drop down menu in it that I am doing for a bootcamp.  It is supposed to look like the Yelp reviews section.

The menu almost works correctly but when it drops down the items the whole top section resizes itself to display the menu instead of just displaying the drop down menu on top of what is already there.  I tried display, zindex, positioning absolute and relative CSS but nothing seems to work. What can I try next?

The repo for this is https://github.com/hrsf93-welp/welp-review but does not contain the MongoDB data.

Comment: Can you please post your code as an example so we can try to replicate the error?

Comment: Without the code is hard to tell, normally positioning absolute should take the element out of the flow of the rest of the page and should not interact with other elements.